# Parse CSV headers that have singular spaces inbetween header names but larger spaces between columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am parsing netstat data and my data looks like this

| Proto Local Address Foreign Adress State PID Process name |
| --- |
| TCP [0.0.0.0:7] 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING 4112 tcpsvcs.exe |
| TCP 0.0.0.0:111 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING 4 Can not obtain ownership information |

When I try to parse this using this Python command

```
pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\Documents\\test.csv", on_bad_lines='skip', header=1, delim_whitespace= True)
```

my data ends up looking like this (Notice how Process_name isn't properly filled out and everything is being shifted to the left due to the space between Local address and foreign address):

| Proto | Local | Address | Foreign | Address | State | PID | Process_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TCP | [0.0.0.0:7] |  | 0.0.0.0:0 | LISTENING | 4112 | tcpsvcs.exe |  |
| TCP | 0.0.0.0:111 | 0.0.0.0:0 |  | LISTENING | 4 | Can not obtain ownership information |  |

When it should end up looking like this:

| Proto | Local Address | Foreign Address | State | PID | Process_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TCP | [0.0.0.0:7] | 0.0.0.0:0 | LISTENING | 4112 | tcpsvcs.exe |
| TCP | 0.0.0.0:111 | 0.0.0.0:0 | LISTENING | 4 | Can not obtain ownership information |

And that's solely due to the spacing of the headers. Right now I am just adding my own headers to my CSV file but the only issue with that is my file is extremely large and appending a header row at the top of a CSV is very heavy. I was wondering if there are any ways to parse the header that I do have and ignore the singular space and only delimit the spaces that are larger than the singular space that I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sep='\s\s+'` on `read_csv` to separate columns that are separated by more than one space:

**Example Data**

```
sim_csv = io.StringIO(
'''  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID    Process_name
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4      tcpsvcs.exe   
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1552   Can not obtain ownership information''')
```

**Execute**

```
df = pd.read_csv(sim_csv, sep='\s\s+')
print(df)
```

**Result**

```
   Proto Local Address Foreign Address      State   PID                          Process_name 
0   TCP    0.0.0.0:80       0.0.0.0:0  LISTENING     4                            tcpsvcs.exe 
1   TCP   0.0.0.0:135       0.0.0.0:0  LISTENING  1552   Can not obtain ownership information
```

Comment: I always use `\s{2,}`, there are plenty of options~

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test it with the raw file but try this:

```
pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\Documents\\test.csv", on_bad_lines='skip', header=1, sep="\t")
```

Comment: I already tried that and tried it now as well. Doesn't seem to do anything except keep everything in one row